Category of elements as a comma category
Riehl's "Category Theory in Context" proves that the category of elements of a functor $F$ can be construed as a certain comma category like this:

The Yoneda lemma supplies an alternative definition of the category of elements of $F$. In the contravariant case, objects $(c, x) \in \int F$ are in bijection with the natural transformations $\Psi(x) : C(—, c) \Rightarrow F$ whose domain is a represented functor and whose codomain is $F$. A morphism from $\Psi(x)$ to a second element $\Psi(x') : C(—, c') \Rightarrow F$ is a natural transformation $C(—, c) \Rightarrow C(—, c')$ — i.e., [by Yoneda embedding] is a morphism $f : c \rightarrow c'$ — so that the triangle of natural transformations
$$
\Psi(x) = \Psi(x') \circ f_*
$$
commutes. This proves that the category of elements can be reconstructed as a comma category.
Lemma 2.4.7. For $F : C^{op} \rightarrow Set$, the category of elements is isomorphic to the comma category $\int F \cong y \downarrow F$ defined relative to the Yoneda embedding $y : C \rightarrow Set^{C^{op}}$ and the object $F : \mathbf{1} \rightarrow Set^{C^{op}}$.

Now, a morphism in $y \downarrow F$ is a pair of natural transformations $C(—, c) \Rightarrow C(—, c')$ and some $\eta : F \Rightarrow F$ such that the corresponding square commutes. The diagram above effectively has $\eta = 1_F$, and I can't quite convince myself that's the only possible choice of a $F \Rightarrow F$, unless we put stronger requirements on $f$ and $\Psi$ (like them being isos). In other words, what prevents $y \downarrow F$ from having morphisms $(f_*, \eta)$ for non-identity $\eta$'s?

Please avoid using images to convey mathematical information not otherwise present in your post. Here is why.  I understand the commutative diagrams are difficult to typeset, but you can include just the diagrams together with the necessary equalities.

@ArturoMagidin Do you know a good way of typesetting commutative triangles here? I know how commutative rectangles work, also fake-triangles (rectangles where one arrow is the identity).

@MartinBrandenburg I am not aware of any particularly good way to have MathJax do triangles (though this question has a decent one).

Updated, thanks!

A morphism in $y \downarrow F$ is just a morphism $c \to c'$ (making the triangle commute), because $F$ here stands for a functor out of the terminal category $\mathbb{1}$ and the only morphism in $\mathbb{1}$ is the identity.
